# Is the reception completed if a receiver gets one foot in bounds and then he steps on his own foot instead of getting the other foot down?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

As the title explains, if the receiver gets one foot down, then he steps on his own foot and gets out of bounds, is it considered a valid catch or no?

Answer (score 4):

According to the NFL [rule Book - #8 section 1](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-video-rulebook/completing-a-catch/), it's an incomplete pass. A completed pass is called when the player

> a. secures control of the ball in his hands or arms prior to the ball touching the ground; and
>
> b. touches the ground inbounds **with both feet or with any part of his body other than his hands**; and
>
> c. after (a) and (b) have been fulfilled, performs any act common to the game

In the case you describe, only one foot and no other part of the body touches the ground.