# A receiver catching the ball on top of a player then going of bounds

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

If a receiver catches a ball near the sidelines, but the defender falls down, and then the receiver lands on the defender and goes out of bounds, is it a catch?
This is assumes that if there was no  defender the landing would result in a completion.

This is similar to the rule where you are not downed when you land on another player but get up without touching the ground.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/29431/is-the-reception-completed-if-a-receiver-gets-one-foot-in-bounds-and-then-he-ste